Gadget Matrix Ring Setting
What would be the analogue of the gadget matrix in the ring setting? Would it be the same matrix? Do the trapdoor algorithms work exactly the same way?
Thanks

You take the gadget matrix over the integers and tensor with an appropriate basis of the ring, see page 8 of lattice gadget toolkit. If you want more explicit examples, the OpenFHE codebase has some.
It also has (ring) trapdoor implementations.

That's whats up! Appreciate it g
